# When using EGit Eclipse loses autocompleting and more

Tags: eclipse, git, autocomplete, egit, highlighting

I have been using Eclipse and CDT for some months but one month ago I set EGit for git integration. Since this moment I lost autocompleting, error highlighting... Now my Eclipse is like a simple text editor =(.

I have readed in Internet and it seems to be usual... but all info is too old =(.

Anyone has EGit with all funcionality? How can I fix it?

Thank you so much =)

EDIT: The info I saw http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/366374/

EDIT2: The Konstantin Komissarchik solution works for me: take a .project file from a copy of your project and copy to the actual .project the differences. In my case these was

```
    <buildSpec>
            <buildCommand>
                    <name>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.genmakebuilder</name>
                    <triggers>clean,full,incremental,</triggers>
                    <arguments>
                    </arguments>
            </buildCommand>
            <buildCommand>
                    <name>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ScannerConfigBuilder</name>
                    <triggers>full,incremental,</triggers>
                    <arguments>
                    </arguments>
            </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
            <nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.cnature</nature>
            <nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.ccnature</nature>
            <nature>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.managedBuildNature</nature>
            <nature>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ScannerConfigNature</nature>
    </natures>
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common cause of the behavior that you are describing is not adding project metadata files to your source repository. Make sure that files and folders starting with '.' in project root, such as .project and .settings, have been added to your repo.

Note that you need to do this from a wherever you initially shared the project from, so that you get the correct metadata that worked before.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I copied all files in another folder and created a new project. This project had all features I miss :(. There was a new .cproject file and I copied it into my git project, restarted Eclipse and nothing :(.

Comment: Diff other '.' files between working and non-working projects. Once you've made all necessary updates, right-click on the project in Eclipse and choose refresh. An Eclipse restart may also be necessary at this point.

Comment: OMG! Yesterday I missed diff .project file! I had "diffed" all other but no this. All is working right now after copying the content of the good .project file (but no name) =). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your issue is related to EGit. Although I don't use CDT very often, by I sometimes see similar issues with the Java editor, and it almost always related to content assist provider getting turned off.

A quick search turned up that such a feature also exists for CDT, so I would look at the CDT content provider preferences. For details see also the following SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5691559/114313

Comment: As I said to Konstantin, I copied all files in another folder and create a new project and all is going OK. In the EGit project is the only one I miss all features :(. Content assist is enabled in my Eclipse...